# "Cannot find symbol" problem when using Class.forName()

Tags: java

I'm getting the `cannot find symbol` error from my code. Does anyone know what can cause this problem?

The code is:

```
// Register JDBC driver
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

and the error output is:

```
blah.java:314: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method forName(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.Class
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                     ^
1 error
```

---

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExample {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.sql.jdbc.Driver";

   static final String DB_URL = (":jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/tempdb" );





   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "password";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection

      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating database...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      String sql = "CREATE DATABASE ";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      System.out.println("Database created successfully...");
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye");
}//end main
}//end JDBCExample
```

Comment: please ask a question, don't just post an error message.

Comment: @joseph, I tried to clean up the question to make it more answerable. Please let me know if I've changed the intent wrongly. And are you actually using GWT as I surmise?

Comment: @paxdiablo: This question has been overzealously edited.  Can you change it back to reflect the fact that the first Class.forName... is the code, and everything from method... onward is the compiler error output?

Comment: i see a ending double quote missing.Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: Okay, bods, I've changed it to reflect your comments after checking what's actually output by javac for a missing method - I particularly love the subtle "overzealously edited" comment :-) Hopefully, that's closer to the original intent now. If you could confirm, @joseph, that would be good.

Comment: It's not gwt.
It's java.
I want to use a java database
Here is the whole code 
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExample {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.sql.jdbc.Driver";

   static final String DB_URL = (":jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/tempdb" );

Comment: I can't put my whole code.There is not enough room.

Comment: Which Java are you using? Class.forName has been around forever and GWT is the only system I know of that doesn't support it. If you're using Sun's or Eclipse's default compiler, it should work fine. That code you posted compiles perfectly under Java6/Windows (javac 1.6.0_14). Please post the _exact_ error message and the steps you're taking to compile it.

Comment: java version "1.6.0_20"
C:\Documents and Settings\ABC\My Documents\JDBCExample.java:24: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method forName(java.lang.String)
location: class Class
      Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
           ^
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1

Comment: @rafael, I'm not sure I can help you then. If that version is indeed the one being used, something's seriously broken. The code you posted compiles fine on my box at the same major version as yours. The only things I can suggest are to (1) try install that Java on a fresh machine and see if you still have the problem, and (2) ensure that `forName` is exactly the method you're calling. Other than that, I can't think of anything else off the top of my head. As I stated, Class.forName has been in Java for a long time and GWT is the only environment I know of that doesn't have it.

Answer (score 3):

The main way in which `Class.forName()` can fail is not having the JDBC drivers available on the class path but that would be a run-time error, not a compile-time error as you seem to be getting here.

Using my powers of psychic debugging, I think you may be using GWT. I don't believe it allows that on the client side (where it's converted to JavaScript). All JDBC stuff has to stay on the server side. Google themselves publish the [JRE emulation reference](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&s=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&t=RefJreEmulation) so you can see what is allowed.

The supported methods of `Class` are limited to:

- desiredAssertionStatus()
- getEnumConstants()
- getName()
- getSuperclass()
- isArray()
- isEnum()
- isInterface()
- isPrimitive()
- toString()

If I am right about the fact you're using GWT, it's probably best to use GWT-RPC to talk between the client and server, and have the server itself issue JDBC calls.

If you want further information on GWT-RPC, see [here](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&s=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&t=GettingStartedRPC). There's a [thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-web-toolkit@googlegroups.com/msg09657.html) in the GWT news group which you can read for further information.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a scenario where you have a class named *"Class.java"* in the same package. In that case it ignores the *"Class.java"* in *java.lang* package. Since you didn't implement a method called *"forName()"* in your *"Class.java"*, it throws this error.

It occurred to me when I got a similar compile-time error.